# how to add text at end of html tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown selection tag as

```
    <select id="_users_add_dropDown" class="form-control style-scope view-work-organizer" style="width: 100% !important; bottom: 0;" required="">
  <option value="View" class="style-scope view-work-organizer" selected="">
                        VIEW</option>
                  <option value="Edit" class="style-scope view-work-organizer">
                EDIT</option>
         <option> </option></select>
```

I want to add at end of
    `<select id="_users_add_dropDown" class="form-control style-scope view-work-organizer" style="width: 100% !important; bottom: 0;" required="">`

into

```
`<select id="_users_add_dropDown" class="form-control style-scope view-work-organizer" style="width: 100% !important; bottom: 0;" required="" onclick=alert('test');>`
```

I want to do using `JavaScript`. I tried

```
var x = document.getElementById("_users_add_dropDown");
        var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text = "alert('1'); </script>
";
 x.add(option);
```

This is not what i want as it add `alert('1')` as drop-down option I want it to appear at end of html tag.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are asking to add an attribute to the html element, so you should not use the createElement method.

have you tried this ?

```
    document.getElementById("_users_add_dropDown").setAttribute('onclick', "alert('test')");
```